# Windows Service in Azure Container Will Not Start

Tags: windows, azure, service, containers

I am working on a POC to run a windows service in a Azure Container Instance. I have created docker containers that run our service based on windows:1809 and servercore:ltsc2019. When I run the image locally using docker the service starts and runs correctly. I am running the container locally using hyper-v isolation. I have uploaded the images to my Azure container Registry and created an instances of them yet when I start the container the service will not start. The service is installed but not in a running state.

The service is installed and should be started with the container starts.

```
PS C:\> Get-Service My*
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  MyService      My Service
```

If I attempt to start the service from the command line I get this error:

```
PS C:\> Start-Service MyService
Start-Service : Service 'My Service (MyService)' cannot be
started due to the following error: Cannot start service MyService on
computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service MyService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControl
   ler:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
   ds.StartServiceCommand
```

If I use net command I get the following:

```
PS C:\> net start MyService
The service is not responding to the control function.
```

The event log has a 1053 error with the message that the timeout was reached after 30 seconds. I ran the start-service from the command line and the log entry did not take 30 seconds to be entered, it is added almost immediatly. I have run the start command using ContainerAdministrator, then added ContainerAdministrator to the local Administrators, and ran a powershell session as a different local administrator to the same results.

Here is the event log:

```
PS C:\> $A = Get-EventLog -LogName system -Newest 7
PS C:\> $A | Select-Object -Property *
EventID            : 7000
MachineName        : wk-caas-28c951151b41452385daba69f308873d-bd43b2406c94ac918
                     8077a
Data               : {80, 0, 51, 0...}
Index              : 1126
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
EntryType          : Error
Message            : The My Service service failed to start due
                     to the following error:
                     %%1053
Source             : Service Control Manager
ReplacementStrings : {My Service, %%1053}
InstanceId         : 3221232472
TimeGenerated      : 4/16/2020 8:46:09 PM
TimeWritten        : 4/16/2020 8:46:09 PM
UserName           :
Site               :
Container          :

EventID            : 7009
MachineName        : wk-caas-28c951151b41452385daba69f308873d-bd43b2406c94ac918
                     8077a
Data               : {80, 0, 51, 0...}
Index              : 1125
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
EntryType          : Error
Message            : A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting
                     for the My Service service to connect.
Source             : Service Control Manager
ReplacementStrings : {30000, My Service}
InstanceId         : 3221232481
CimeGenerated      : 4/16/2020 8:46:09 PM
TimeWritten        : 4/16/2020 8:46:09 PM
UserName           :
Site               :
Container          :
```

I am new to docker, containers, and Azure and cannot find a reason why my service would not respond in a timely manner or why the log entry would be added in less than the 30 seconds the log reports, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing same issue :(